# jQuery validate invalidHandler with alert still submits in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, submit, validation

Can't fathom this at all.
Using validate jQuery (1.6.2) with validate plugin (1.8.1).
Have the following invalidHandler code which works fine in all browsers if the submit button is clicked. 
However, if the form is submit by hitting enter on the keyboard after filling any field in, in Firefox (versions 5 and 6 anyway), you get the alert about the number of errors but the form still submits anyway!
The form is not submit in other browsers, and if the alert line is removed, it works fine in Firefox. But we need the alert, so if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this it would be *greatly* appreciated - I'm not used to things acting up just in Firefox! :)

```
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
           var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
           if (errors)
           {
                   var message = (errors == 1)
                     ? '1 field has an error. It has been highlighted'
                     : errors + ' fields have errors. They have been highlighted';
                     alert(message);
                     //return false;
           }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uncommenting out `return false`?

[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) indicates that `false` will:

> ...cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event
>   object or by returning false from our handler.

Comment: Yes JW - sorry forgot to mention that I had only added in the return false bit in debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue occur as well. What I *think* is going on is that a call to alert() blocks execution of the invalidHandler function, which breaks the way jQuery.validate would normally function.

What you can do is launch an alert window via a setTimeout call, which doesn't block execution of your invalidHandler code:

```
setTimeout('alert("'+message+'")', 1)
```

Hacky, but works!